# How to hide completed tasks in Apple Mail on Mac?

Tags: mac, apple-mail, tasks

Is there a way to hide completed tasks in the list display in the Apple Mail application on Mac ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "smart mailbox" that only shows your open todos.

Comment: "Smart mailbox" for a to-do list... Kind of weird place to find this ;-)

Comment: Yeah, well in my opinion Mail shouldn't be doing to-dos in the first place. :)

Comment: Indeed, I saw that the tasks are also present in iCal. Indeed, a better place;-) There, you can hide them correctly. I don't know why Mail show them all...